Can an international student email a professor at a foreign university for an internship opportunity?
I was recently ranked 71/+1000 in a national competition (a series of final exams taken to join the country’s big engineering schools) and I am now a mechanical engineering student.
I want to be able to intern abroad. Is it a good idea to email a number of professors whose work and research interest me and ask, or is there no chance?

Are you already a student at the university you want to intern at?

Yes, you can always email and ask. However, internships may be limited based upon specific universities and nationalities as well as other specific poliies.

Voting to leave open, but also down-voting. IMHO this is a legitimate question that is difficult to answer.

Yes, you can email, but, unless they have advertised for interns, expect most of your mails to be ignored. Perhaps you get a polite response saying "not at this time."
Before you mail, you should investigate what they do and how you fit their program. Otherwise, again, ignored or polite "no".
I used to get lots of such requests along with CVs and such where it was obvious they had no idea who I was or what I did. Sent to trash with no reply. That's just the way it is. Blind emails are easy to ignore.
However, one way to, perhaps, find success is if you have a professor who knows you well, make an enquiry on your behalf. It is harder to ignore a mail from a colleague, especially one who is known to them.
Or, examine university departmental websites and faculty web pages looking for opportunities that are advertised. You might find something, but it will take a lot of work to do it.
(I truly love your user name)

Why? You get some bright, motivated young person, recently educated in your field, to work on research ideas you don't have time for. You will probably get a publication out of it, why say 'no'?

@Ivana The problem with blind emails is that it is not obvious whether the person who is emailing is capable of working on research ideas. This is why a recommendation from a professor can help! Or a tailored message that demonstrates familiarity with a specific professors' research. But mass emails have to go straight to trash, because there is simply not enough time to sort through these students. I don't think professors should feel guilty about this; they're devoting as much time to the student as the student devoted to them (none).

@Ivana Managing juniors is a job. You cannot just toss them a "research idea you don’t have time for" and collect a free coauthorship six months later. You have to follow up on their progress, help them when they are stuck, etc. From my experience, even the most self-sufficient interns need 1h/week of supervision on a good week (30-40min weekly meeting + a couple of very short chats here and there); it easily shoots up to 5h/week or more if the intern is stuck on a tricky point or if there is paperwork to sort out. (...)

(...) Also, that is a purely utilitarian perspective of "giving my work drones just enough maintenance that they continue working". I would argue that as a supervisor you have ethical duties beyond that - for instance, you will "waste" time explaining stuff (when you could refer them to Wikipedia or a standard paper), or helping them navigate university admin, or letting them attend seminars (which does not make them more productive in the short run).

You also need to arrange for their visas, and arrange to pay them (unless it's volunteer), finding a source of funds not restricted to citizens.  It's not a small lift, and there are easier pools to target.

@Ivana is also worth pointing out that unpaid internships are illegal in some countries.

Yes it is totally possible, I've secured internships two years in a row like this.
As pointed out before, most of your emails will stay unanswered, but emails are free, and you have nothing to lose.
It helps to do some research about the professors you're contacting though, maybe read a couple of their publications, and explain why you are interested in what they do.

Upvoted, I've secured the internship that I used for my master thesis this way. Be aware you will probably have to pay your own way during your internship. But maybe your university has some program to help you.

On the other hand, consider the faculty getting "free" emails from students from all over with "nothing to [lose]."

As far as I know, both my supervisors were quite happy I contacted them.

Yes you can totally try this! Make sure to write a specific e-mail, that is, know the professor's work and list some topics that you work on, as well as skills/knowledge that you have and will come in helpful. There will always be researchers that do not have time/aren't interested, but you can try to pique their interest that way. I got one of my MSc placements by reading about an open postdoc position in their lab, and asking to do something similar.
In addition, it helps if you can show that you thought this through: show them possible funds (within the EU, Erasmus is the go-to option) that will support you through the visit, and maybe link to information about your study programme and thesis requirements.
